# get all data from dynamo db table without supplying any PK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch all the data from my dynamodb table but unable to get as all the methods for Query / Scan operates with input parameter. so i tried getting all the rows which having primary key greater than 0.

```
        var table = Table.LoadTable(client,Utilities.Utility.EmployeeTable);

        ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter();
        filter.AddCondition("iemp_id", ScanOperator.GreaterThan, 0);

        ScanOperationConfig config = new ScanOperationConfig()
        {
            Filter = filter,
            // Optional parameters.
            Select = SelectValues.SpecificAttributes,
            AttributesToGet = new List<string> { "iemp_id", "demp_salary", "semp_name" }
            //ConsistentRead = true
        };

        Search search = table.Scan(config);`
```

Here i am getting search.Matches = 0 where it should return data from my table.

Answer (score 0):

You have only two options

1.Query : You need to supply Partition Key(mandatory) and optionally Range key.
2.Scan: Full scan of the table with out Partition key/Range Key.

In your case you will have to do full scan of the table.

DynamoDBQScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
                scanExpression .withFilterExpression(filterexpression)
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(expression values);